# Insert into table access 2010

Tags: ms-access-2010

How can i copy contents of my whole table in sql access and update one column to the same table.

So basically is selecting the whole table and updating one column and pasting that to the same table. thanks.

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you need. First you say 'how can I copy... whole table' AND 'update one column'. Do you mean you want to: (a) copy a table, then (b) update a table; or do you simply mean 'I want to update all rows in one table'. Are you trying to manually do this or via code or an update query? (pasting, to me, implies manually)

Comment: sorry for not explaining... Im trying to use use a query to copy all the contents of my table AND update just one column. So all the data would stay the same. but the 'state' column would change from "NY" to "FL" for example. Im using access 2010. Thanks.

Comment: You keep using the term 'copy', but you don't explain what you will do with the 'copy'.  Will you paste it somewhere else? I am guessing (which doesn't help either of us) that you want to do ONE of the following: (A) Copy all data from TableA into TableB and change STATECODE values at the same time; or (B) you only want to update STATECODE values in TableA. Using a query? VBA?

Comment: sorry.. I want to keep the data in one table. so it would be selecting all the fields A-Z and Inserting the data back to the same table and updating one of the columns to a different state.

Answer (score 0):

To clone an existing table back into the same table, but using a different value for one field, use something like the following (see notes that follow!):

```
INSERT INTO Table1 ( FldA, FldB, MyDate, StateCode )
SELECT Table1.FldA, Table1.FldB, Table1.MyDate, "FL" AS Expr1
FROM Table1;
```

You can't easily use the * to select/update all fields because your need to change one field would result in a "duplicate destination" error. If needed, you could use an 'IF' statement to change to different values (i.e. IF(FldA="VA","FL",IF(FldA="MD","TX",Flda))

Comment: yea the above query is just a simple update. I want to retain the state code from the original table. so it would be NY with all fields. then FL... ect ect.

Comment: This is really not very clear. You say 'retain the state code', but don't say where? In the original field in the original table? If that's true, where do you expect the updated field to be stored? A new field? A new table? Reading back your original question, at first I thought you you may want to copy all records to a new table and change the state code. BUT you said 'to the same table'. Do you want to copy all existing records from Table1, insert them back into the same table, but change the new records state code?  Please explain.

Comment: "Do you want to copy all existing records from Table1, insert them back into the same table, but change the new records state code? "
yes this is exactly what I want... not sure if it could be done...